# Display contents of List<T> in a .txt file via a class

Tags: c#, .net, listbox

I am fairly new to programming so please have some patience whilst I try and explain! I've been looking over this specific method for a while now and it may just be simple, however, I want to display all the items I have in a listbox to a .txt file. However it just displays the following in my text file:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[QA.OrderItem]
```

My save method is in one class and I have an **overriden** .ToString in a separate class that is correctly display the list items in the listbox instead of:

```
System.Collections.Generic.BlahBlahBlah
```

I though I could use a foreach loop (which will use my overriden .ToString) that will iterate through my list and write to the text file, however, this didn't seem to work!

Any help would be much appreciated and thank you for your time (please see all necessary code below).

Save method in the `ShoppingBasket` class:

```
public bool SaveBasket(string fileName)
{
    // A string that specifies a subfolder to be made.
    string path = @"C:\Users\Public\BasketSaves";

    // Create the subfolder.
    if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) { 
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    }

    // Combine the filename to the end of the path.
    path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName + ".txt");

    // Check that the file doesn't exsist. If it doesn't, create 
    // the file and write the list box to it.
    if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path)) {
        System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, OrderItems.ToString());
        // Return true when the file doesn't exsist.
        return true;
    }
    else {
        // Return false when the file exsists.
        return false;
    }
}
```

Overriden `.ToString()` in `OrderItem` class:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return string.Format("{0}\t {1}\t {2}",ProductName, LatestPrice, Quantity);
}
```

**EDIT**

`OrderItem` class:

```
public class OrderItem : IOrderItem {

    public OrderItem(string productName, decimal latestPrice):this(productName, latestPrice, 1) {

    }

    public OrderItem(string productName, decimal latestPrice, int quantity) {
        this.ProductName = productName;
        this.LatestPrice = latestPrice;
        this.Quantity = quantity;
    }

    /******************* Properties *******************/ 

    public string ProductName { get; private set; } 
    public decimal LatestPrice { get; private set; }
    public decimal TotalOrder { get;  private set; }
    public int Quantity { get; private set; }        

    /*************************************************/ 

    /// <summary>
    /// Add multiple items to a basket with a new latest price
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="latestPrice">Takes the latest price of a specified product</param>
    /// <param name="numberOfItems">Takes the amount you wish to add</param>
    /// <returns>The quantity</returns>
    public int AddItems(decimal latestPrice, int numberOfItems) {
        if (numberOfItems <= 0 || latestPrice < 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        LatestPrice = latestPrice;
        Quantity += numberOfItems;

        // Return the Quantity value.
        return Quantity;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add multiple items (no price change functionality)
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="numberOfItems">Takes the amount you wish to add</param>
    /// <returns>The quantity</returns>
    public int AddItems(int numberOfItems) {
        if (numberOfItems <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }
        return Quantity += numberOfItems;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an item with incrementation
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Incrementation then the Quantity value</returns>
    public int AddItem() {
        return ++Quantity;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Add multiple items
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="numberOfItems">Takes the amount you wish to subtract</param>
    /// <returns>The quantity</returns>
    public int RemoveItems(int numberOfItems)  {

        Quantity -= numberOfItems;

        if (numberOfItems <= 0) {
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException();
        }

        if (Quantity < 0) {
            return Quantity = 0;
        }

        // Return the Quantity if the above is false.
        return Quantity;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Adds an item with decrementation 
    /// </summary>
    /// <returns>Decrement then the Quantity value</returns>
    public int RemoveItem() {
        return --Quantity;
    }

    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}\t {1}\t {2}",ProductName, LatestPrice, Quantity);
    }
}
```

`ShoppingBasket` class:

```
public class ShoppingBasket : IShoppingBasket
{
    public ShoppingBasket()
    {
        OrderItems = new List<OrderItem>();
    }

    public List<OrderItem> OrderItems { get; private set; }

    public int NumberOfProducts {
        get {
           return OrderItems.Count();
        }
    }

    public decimal BasketTotal { get; private set; }

    public int NumberOfItems {
        get {
            return OrderItems.Count();
        }
    }

    public void AddProduct(string productName, decimal latestValue, int quantity = 1) {
        OrderItems.Add(new OrderItem(productName, latestValue));
    }

    public void RemoveProducts(string productName, int quantity = 1) {
        OrderItems.Remove(new OrderItem (productName, quantity));
    }

    public void ClearBasket() {
        OrderItems.Clear();
    }

    public bool SaveBasket(string fileName)
    {
        // A string that specifies a subfolder to be made.
        string path = @"C:\Users\Public\BasketSaves";

        // Create the subfolder.
        if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) { 
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        }

        // Combine the filename to the end of the path.
        path = System.IO.Path.Combine(path, fileName + ".txt");

        // Check that the file doesn't exsist. If it doesn't, create 
        // the file and write the list box to it.
        if (!System.IO.File.Exists(path)) {

            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, OrderItems.ToString());

            // Return true when the file doesn't exsist.
            return true;
        }
        else {
            // Return false when the file exsists.
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

This allows the user to add an item to the basket:

```
    private void btnAdd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) {
        OrderItem item = new OrderItem(txtName.Text, Convert.ToDecimal(txtLatestPrice.Text), Convert.ToInt32(txtQuantity.Value));
        lbBasket.Items.Add(item.ToString());
    }
```

Comment: Post the code that shows/creates OrderItems. Though, the problem is your method overrides a single OrderItem To string and there is no default functionality to loop through ToString() of items contained in the collection.

Comment: Post the loop that did not work.

Comment: @Blam I have edited the post accordingly.

Comment: Have you tried using `foreach ( OrderItem item in OrderItems )...` instead of var in your loop?

Comment: @Gorgsenegger Yup, I already tried that but it didn't work!

Comment: @Gorgsenegger: This makes no difference. `var` tells the compiler to infer the real type, but the `item` will be typed `OrderItem` in any case; whether you specify it explicitly or not.

Comment: According to another comment OrderItems is empty.  Show where you add and anything to OrderItems.

Comment: @Blam I have updated the post to show this now!

Comment: That is how you add an item to the basket.  You state OrderItems is empty.  Did you actually add an item and verify that code ran without error?

Comment: @Blam The code runs fine and works. The only problem, is just getting the listbox contents that the user adds to display in my textfile via my ShoppingBasket class!

Comment: If that code runs fine then explain why OrderItems is empty!  Did you verify that AddProduct is called?  No you have not!

Comment: @Josh: This is a completely different question and has nothing to do with writings items to a file. Please ask a new question, if you need to know how to link a form with a model. You also might want to read about *data binding* and patterns like *MVC*, *MVP* or *MVVM* (mainly for WPF).

Comment: @Josh: Your `btnAdd_Click` adds items to the listbox but not to the `OrderItems` list. I suggest you to add the items like this: `OrderItems.Add(theNewOrderItem); lbBasket.DataSource = null; lbBasket.DataSource = OrderItems;`. Don't use `lbBasket.Items.Add(...);`!

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Why did you bail the OP out?  Teach them to fish.  This person needs to learn how to debug.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Thank you! I seemed to just look straight past this and didn't realize! Thank you for help on my first concern as well! :)

Comment: @Blam: I helped the OP a lot; however, each time someone answers him a question he is asking a new one. This is not a chat room and not a debugging forum but a question and answer site. Changing the question after answers have been given makes it difficult to understand earlier answers and the comments lists tend to get very long.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes Yea, sorry about that. It's my first time on here, however, I'll remember for future though! Thank you very much for your time Olivier.

Comment: @OlivierJacot-Descombes So OPs questions changed but the problem did not.  On the 7th comment I asked the proper question.  I still you contend you let OP off the hook rather than force the OP to address the problem. If they don't know how to ask the question then make them address the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling `WriteAllText` in a loop and thus replacing the whole file with the current item at each iteration.

---

Every type in .NET inherits the method `ToString()` from `System.Object` alias `object`. The default implementation for `ToString()` is to display the type name. Types other than `object` must override `ToString()` if they want to provide another behavior.

`OrderItems` is a collection (`List<T>`). Collections usually don't override `ToString()` and do therefore display their type name when converted to strings. You have to iterate over a collection and to concatenate the string representation of its items in order to get an adequate string representation of the collection's content.

Since you have overridden `ToString()` in `OrderItem` you can convert the `List<OrderItem>` like this:

```
// Until .NET 3.5
string s = String.Join("\r\n", OrderItems.Select(o => o.ToString()).ToArray());

// From .NET 4.0
string s = String.Join("\r\n", OrderItems.Select(o => o.ToString()));
```

Starting with .NET Framework 4.0 `File.WriteAllLines` has an overloaded version accepting an enumeration as well. This has the advantage over using a `ToArray()` that an enumeration is evaluated lazily and that the result must not be kept in memory as a whole.

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename, OrderItems.Select(o => o.ToString()));
```

Or you can loop over the list and write the items one by one to the file.

---

**UPDATE**

Since you converted the items to strings when adding them to the listbox (what is not really necessary since the list box does it automatically when displaying the items) you can also write the file like this:

```
File.WriteAllLines(filename, lbBasket.Cast<string>());
```

You still need the cast, since the `ObjectCollection` used by `ListBox` is not a generic collection, i.e. it implements `IEnumerable` but not `IEnumerable<T>`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your solution! I tried your solution, however, it just produces an empty text file. I imagine there is something; somewhere that I've missed out!

Comment: I also noticed that you write the list `OrderItems` to the file and not the list box items as asked in the title. Is `OrderItems.Count > 0`?.

Comment: Indeed, all of the work is being done from the classes. I am not writing the save method directly in the form code (sorry for not making that clear). Also from a bit of debugging I've just done, `OrderItems.Count` is returning 0.

Comment: Please view my further addition which shows my `List<OrderItem>` property (Should that be any benefit).

Comment: In this case you can simply add the items to the listbox with `lbBasket.DataSource = OrderItems;` (once you have really added items to the list :-) ). Have you a `OrderItems.Add(item);` somewhere? Is it really called?

Comment: I have added both classes that are being used in the application, just so you can see what's happening! Just saves me trying (not very well) to explain! :)

Comment: The method `AddProduct` seems to be correct. Now it depends where you are calling it and whether you are using the right instance of basket. You might be adding items to one basket and trying to write antoher empty basket to the file.

Answer (score 1):

One approach I would suggest is to loop through your collection writing out each item.

```
var sb = new StringBuilder();
foreach(var item in OrderItems)
{
    // send item to the text file or build a string using StringBuilder
    sb.AppendLine(item.ToString());
}
// now dump sb.ToString() to your text file
```

MSDN has a great example of how to write text to a file:

[Write text to a file](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6ka1wd3w%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

Try the following

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllLines(path, (IEnumerable<string>)OrderItems.Items);
```

It's off the top of my head so not sure if it'll work.

Otherwise just do

```
StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

using(System.IO.StreamWriter writer = new System.IO.StreamWriter(path)
{
    foreach(string item in OrderItems.Items)
    {
        builder.append(string.format("{0}{1}", item, Environment.NewLine));
    }

    writer.write(builder.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't I only be able to use .Items in my forms code? All of the above methods (apart from the one mentioned) are in a classes.

Comment: A bit of linq should allow you to convert it for use in another class. var mylist = OrderItems.Items.Cast<String>().ToList();

Answer (score 0):

Currently you are writing

```
OrderItems.ToString():
```

To the file and the will not loop on items
It will just give a systems message of what OrderItems is

In your other loop code you looped on the file
Better to build up the content and then write once
Try this

```
if(OrderItems != null && OrderItems.Count > 0)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (var item in OrderItems)
    {
         Debug.WriteLine(item.ToString());
         sb.AppendLine(item.ToString());
    }
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, sb.ToString());
}
else 
{
    Debug.WriteLine("Nothing to write.");
    System.IO.File.WriteAllText(path, "No items");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your loop didnt work because the WriteAllText methods writes text per file.
If you really want to use  this method concate all the values into one string
before writing. Or use StreamWriter instead.